# In python how to replace a substring in a string without using replace method and using join method?

Tags: python-3.x, string, join, substring

How can replace the `find_string` with `replace_string` in `target_string` using .join method in python or any other method excluding replace()

```
target_string="Maybe she's born with it. Maybe it's Maybelline."
find_string = "Maybe"
replace_string = "Perhaps"
def replace_all(target_string, find_string, replace_string):


replace_all(target_string, find_string, replace_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split` and `str.join`. For example:

```
target_string = "Maybe she's born with it. Maybe it's Maybelline."
find_string = "Maybe"
replace_string = "Perhaps"


def replace_all(target_string, find_string, replace_string):
    while find_string in target_string:
        target_string = replace_string.join(target_string.split(find_string))
    return target_string


print(replace_all(target_string, find_string, replace_string))
```

Prints:

```
Perhaps she's born with it. Perhaps it's Perhapslline.
```

Comment: Thank You So much :)